# Sweave Print Codes without Considering the Width of Paper

Tags: pdftex, paper-size, sweave

I changed my paper size to A3 in order to make certain code chunk displayed without disruption. However, it seems that Sweave is not smart enough to detect the change of paper size and still break lines as if it is A4 paper as show below. Clearly, there is enough space to print the matrix without any line breaks. How do I tell Sweave to do that, please? Thanks. FYI, my codes are as follows.

```
\documentclass[english, hidelinks, 11pt, landscape]{exam}

\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<>>=
x <- matrix(1:15)
y <- matrix(20:40, nrow=1)
x%*%y
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do I need R installed to compile this document?  Anyway, my guess is that you should add `a3paper` to the options of `\documentclass`, but I can’t test this.

Comment: @Lorehead Yes, I believe you do need R to do the calculation.

Comment: @Lorehead Adding `a3paper` as you suggested produced error.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  The `\exam` class supports `a4paper, a5paper, b5paper, letterpaper, legalpaper, executivepaper` (per manual).  Does `Sweave` recognize these in the documentclass?

Comment: I dont know what you meant. BTW, I tried your method for article class, it did not work, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither Sweave or Knitr can recognize the paper or text width of the LaTeX document.  You must set the width in the R-chunk.  Simple example follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<>>=
1:200
@

<<>>=
options(width = 25)
1:200
@

<<>>=
options(width=160)
1:200
@

\end{document}
```

[image]